# How to assign filename to Image in Django based on EXIF DateTime

Tags: python, django

I would like to read EXIF information from a user-uploaded image in Django, then use that EXIF info to generate the filename to store the image as (under the `animal_img/alfred-0012` directory), for example:

Original filename: `P1110438.JPG`

Date taken: `2012-07-22`

Name: `Alfred`

Intended filename: `alfred-20120722.jpg`

Somehow, this had been working up until recently, but Django has been complaining about not finding the file with `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'P1110438.JPG'`

The code I've been using in my model to rename the images:

```
def img_namer(instance, filename):
    path = 'animal_img/%s-%04d/' % (instance.name.lower(), instance.id)
    name = instance.name.lower() + Image.open(filename)._getexif()[36867] + ".jpg"

    return os.path.join(path, name)

image = models.ImageField(
    default=None,
    blank=True,
    upload_to=img_namer,

)
```

I can see the limitations with trying to open the ImageFile before it's been properly saved, however this had been working, like I said, so maybe I'm doing something wrong? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found your question while trying to solve a similar problem...

By replacing `Image.open(filename)` with `Image.open(instance.image)` it works for me.